# didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo not called

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a `UITableViewCell` button to take an image and place it back in the cell. When I call the `UIImagePickerController` and take the image, it doesn't call the following delegate:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject], sender:AnyObject)
```

This is my `takePhotoFunction` in `UITableViewController`:

```
@IBAction func takePhoto(sender: AnyObject) {
let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
imagePickerController.delegate = self
imagePickerController.allowsEditing = true

let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Choose image souruce", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)

actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Take Image", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (alert:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
    imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
    self.presentViewController(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}))

actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Photo Library", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (alert:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
    imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    self.presentViewController(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}))
actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil))
self.presentViewController(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)}
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In **Swift 3**, this delegate method is now called:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
```

The differences are:

1. There is an **underline _ before picker**
2. info type at the end is changed from **[String : AnyObject]** to **[String : Any]**

I had the same issue and when I made these changes it worked.

Answer (score 17):

**1. Dont forget to add `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate`

2. In your `viewDidLoad()` add `picker.delegate = self`

3. Add the delegate methods**

```
public func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage 
        userImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        userImageView.image = chosenImage
        dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil)
    }

public func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 7):

For swift 4.2

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
   if let chosenImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage{
        //use image
    }
}
```

Comment: `UIImage?' is not convertible to 'UIImage'`

Comment: `Cast from 'Slice<Dictionary<UIImagePickerController.InfoKey, Any>>' (aka 'Slice<Dictionary<NSString, Any>>') to unrelated type 'UIImage' always fails`

Answer (score 3):

*With the **Swift 5** we have slight update.*

Here is single screen example I have created to test this with iOS 12.2

```
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    //MARK: Open Photos Galley Button Action method
    @IBAction func openPhotosGallery(_ sender: Any) {

        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary){
            let myPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
            myPickerController.delegate = self;
            myPickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
            self.present(myPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    //MARK: ImagePicker Controller Delegate methods
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage
        imageView.image = chosenImage
        dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use below method for Swift 4.2:

```
public func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]){
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For **Swift 4.2**

This method has renamed and now should be called as below. I had the same issue that this delegate method was not calling but after this, my issue resolved.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

for **SWIFT 4.2**

I had a similar issue when delegate methods were not called by program.

The `imagePicker.delegate = self` should be **NOT** in viewDidLoad() method but in method which opens gallery. Like this:

```
func openGallery()
    {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self

        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary

        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

In **Swift 5** we need to use:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any])  {
```

Comment: Worked for me. As I added a tap gesture recognizer to a UIView, the user taps the UIView but the selected image didn't allocate after picker dismiss and the method I used was yellow lined. This method above solved my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to use that method in this way  as there is no delegate method that u have declared:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info:[NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        println("Calling")       
}
```

Reference for Apple Document :https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:

Comment: Hi Dheeraj, thanks for your answer. I have implemented the delegate method but after the imagpepickercontroller has completed, this method is not called.

Comment: did you use the delegate method that i mentioned because you delegate method is not correct and there is no delegate method as u have declared.

Answer (score 0):

The delegate method is now called `func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])`

I see your `imagePickerController.delegate` is correctly set so I would assume that you accidently put the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` code outside your ViewController class

Answer (score 0):

If your UIImagePickerController() object has allowsEditing property set to true then you should get the image in the delegate method as:

if `allowsEditing == true`

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

        if let pickedImage = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage {

              //do something with image

        }

           dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

if `allowsEditing == false`

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

            if let pickedImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {

                  //do something with image

            }

               dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe sometimes it is caused by ARC?
I declare a variable of adapter (present `UIImagePickerController` for pre-iOS14 below or present `PHPickerViewController` for iOS 14+) in controller instead in function.
It works for me.

```
var adapter: PHPickerAdapter?

@objc func openGallery(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    adapter = PHPickerAdapter()
    adapter?.delegate = self
    adapter?.showPhotoPicker(.photoLibrary, from: self)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was because the picker was declared inside a function so it get deallocated once we exit the function

```
func showImagePicker() {
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    present(imagePicker, animated: true)
}
```

The solution was to move the `imagePicker` object to outside the function body

```
lazy var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
func showImagePicker() {
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    present(imagePicker, animated: true)
}
```

I made it lazy var since I want to initialize it only when needed.